# Errno 97 with Android NDK socket programming

Tags: android, sockets, android-ndk

I've searched all over google and can't find a solution to this problem:

I'm trying to do some basic socket programming (client/server apps) on my Android device and I'm not having any luck starting the Server app.  In my native code, I call bind(...) and I see from the log that it returns -1.  When I check errno, the value is 97 (EAFNOSUPPORT), which indicates "Address family not supported by protocol."  When I checked the values for sin_family, it was AF_INET, which is IPv4.  Is this not supported by the Android NDK?  If not, what else could be the cause of this error?

Socket is initialized as:

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP));
```

listenAddr is a sockaddr_in struct that's initialized with:

```
sin_family = AF_INET;
sin_port = htons(9099);
sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_NONE;
```

Call to bind:

```
bindResult = bind(sock, (sockaddr *)listenAddr, sizeof(listenAddr))
```

Bind result returns -1.  Subsequent call to errno returns 97.

Comment: Post your code, or search out known-good examples and make your own detailed comparison. There are several places you can make subtle mistakes, particularly with the size of some of the structs involved.

Comment: Ran this code on Linux and got the same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INADDR_ANY (or a specific interface's address) rather than INADDR_NONE.

INADDR_NONE is an unsigned constant with the same bit pattern as the signed value -1, returned as an indication of error from certain calls.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply.  I was able to make bind(...) socket api call work with those parameters.  The reality of the situation is that I've been asked to port my co-workers code from Windows to Linux/Android and he has his own way of doing things in regards to sockets (wrapper classes & overloaded operators).  His code runs fine in Windows, but when run on a Linux environment, I get errno 97.  For the second argument to bind(...), he passes in a reference to an object that inherits from struct sockaddr_in and casts it to (struct sockaddr *).  Is this permissible in Linux (or GCC)?

Comment: Also, for the third parameter to bind(...), he passes in the sizeof(sockaddr), not the sizeof() the second argument that's being passed into bind(...)

Comment: There are two questions there.  If you hand off a pointer to something in memory which matches the struct the syscall expects, and deliver the accurate size, it can work.  The second question would be if your language allows you to make the syscall with the desired arguments - C assumes you know what you are doing and happily allows this, but C++ might throw up some roadblocks if it has been told that the source data is of an incompatible form.

Comment: The problem actually had to do with one of the way one of the overloaded operators that my co-workers code had worked.  We resolved it this morning but i'll accept this anyway :p